# Ranking optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, ranking

I am looking for a library that I can feed with a list of element rankings from users so that it computes an assignment from users to elements that makes everyone happy.

Each element has an individual maximum number of possible users it can handle.
A single element ranking is an ordering of all elements so that the user who ranked the elements prefers the first one most and the last one least (like first choice, second choice, and so on).
A user is happier, the better his ranking of the element assigned to him is.

What software/libraries are there to solve this common optimization problem?

*Edit*: A mathematical definition of what I want to compute:

Given a finite set U of users, a finite set S of elements and a function c from S to the natural numbers that specifies for each element how many users can be assigned to it.

Each user specifies a ranking R(U) that is a bijective map from S to {1..|S|}.
For a given assignment A: User \to Element, a penalty is defined as the sum of R(u)(A(u))^2 over all users u.
Now I want to find the assignment that minimizes the penalty (or one that is good enough) and considers c by not assigning more than c(e) users to the element e.

Comment: This feels broad as there is not always a solution in the hard-constraint case (for a start: [Condorcet-criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_criterion)). Describe it more formally and make sure you know the differences in potential penalties / objectives. (Mixed-)-integer programming can be a good approach. For some example in regards to (already NP-hard) unconstrained [kemeny-ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemeny%E2%80%93Young_method) (surely something different), see [this](https://github.com/sschnug/kemeny_ranking).

Comment: It would be worth saying a little about the environment you intend to use this in, especially if there are language or platform constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I did a survey where each participant could rank workshops according to his preferences. Each workshop only allows so many participants. Now I have to decide which participant is assigned to which workshop and want to do this in a fair way. I don't care much about which penalty function to use but thought of minimizing the sum of all quadratic ranks of the workshop a participant is assigned to.
I.e. if a participants first choice is A, his second B and he is assigned to B, he contributes a penalty of 2^2 = 4 in contrast to 1 if his first choice was considered.

Comment: Then this can be solved by MISOCP or MIQP solvers (somewhat limited open-source candidates). But the problem is NP-hard.

Comment: Isn't this a common problem though? I thought there must be a ton of software out there doing this kind of optimization. I would even be happy with approximated solutions.

Comment: You might model it as a cost flow problem using Google's open source cost flow solver: 
 https://developers.google.com/optimization/assignment/assignment_min_cost_flow.  I haven't used their cost flow solver, so I can't speak to how well it actually fits your problem.

Comment: As min-cost-flow is in P, this problem here is NP-hard, you can't solve it with  those methods (at least not with a problem-size in P).

Comment: @Henning As it's still broad why asked if it's a common problem. It's even unclear if some people apply for 5 course while other only for 1 and how this is treated. Why not write it down mathematically?

Comment: Each participant is to be assigned to one and only one workshop, correct?

Comment: @sascha I added a mathematical description of the problem I want to solve.

Comment: I still think a cost flow solver is exactly what you're looking for.  Your problem is almost exactly like the first example on the page I linked to earlier, except that the capacity of the arcs into the sink are > 1. The workers are the users, the tasks are the workshops, the costs from user to workshop are the rank-based penalties, and the capacities from workshop to sink are the maximum number of attendees of each workshop.

Comment: I think this solution using [Octave and GLPK](https://dzone.com/articles/algorithms-the-assignment-problem) should work in your [generalized assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem) case as well, just need to set-up the input matrices (a, b, c, etc.) correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - download a program that does exactly what you need from [here](https://gitlab.com/darrylm/assign_to_workshops).

This can be modeled as a cost flow problem. In a cost flow problem, items conceptually flow between nodes along directional arcs.  Each arc has a cost that is incurred each time an item flows between its nodes. Arcs also have a capacity that limits how many items can flow across the arc. And finally, each node has a starting inventory of items. A node can only send an item along one of its attached arcs if it has an item in inventory. The item is transferred from the sending end of the arc to the receiving end of the arc. The receiving node can then send the item along one of its attached arcs to yet another node.  The cost flow solver searches for the set of transfers that sends as many items as it can at the lowest cost.

So what does this have to do with assigning people to workshops?  Well, you can think of each person as having one token that represents their ability to attend one workshop.  They send their token to the workshop they will attend, and the cost (or penalty) of sending that token is a reflection of where that workshop is in the person's prioritized list of workshops.  The workshop a person most wants to attend is very cheap, while the least preferred workshop is very expensive.  Once a workshop gets tokens from attendees, it sends its tokens to a sink node.  The arc between the workshop and the sink node has no cost, but it does have a capacity that indicates the maximum number of people that can attend that workshop.  The optimization will try to get all of the tokens to the sink node, and at the lowest cost.  The only way for every token to get to the sink is if every person goes to one workshop, and if the number of people going to each workshop doesn't exceed the workshop's capacity. The solver finds a way to do that at the lowest cost.

Here's a diagram showing the layout:

[image: Assignment flow network]

There's a node for each person, a node for each workshop, and a sink node.  Numbers in square braces show a node's starting inventory.  Numbers in parentheses show an arc's capacity.  In this example, the maximum number of people that can attend each workshop is 3, 2, and 4, respectively.  Nodes without a starting inventory displayed have a starting inventory of 0, and arcs without a capacity displayed have a capacity of 1.

This can be implemented using Google's open source [cost flow solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/assignment/assignment_min_cost_flow).  I've done just that, and wrapped it into a program that you can [download from gitlab](https://gitlab.com/darrylm/assign_to_workshops). It's written it in such a way that you only have to replace a little bit of C# code to solve your specific problem.  Just replace the workshop and person information shown below with your own data.

```
    // Identifies all workshops, with the maximum number of people that can enroll in each.
    Dictionary<string, int> workshopCapacities = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"A", 2 },
        {"B", 3 },
        {"C", 1 }
    };

    // Identifies each person by name, which maps to a list of workshops they want to attend in the order of preference
    Dictionary<string, string[]> peoplePreferences = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
    {
        { "Betsy", new[]{ "A", "B", "C" } },
        { "Joe",   new[]{ "C", "B", "A" } },
        { "Maria", new[]{ "C", "A", "B" } },
        { "Kuang", new[]{ "C", "A", "B" } },
        { "Paula", new[]{ "B", "C", "A" } },
    };
```

Comment: I got some time to rethink about that and while i did label it NP-hard in my comments above, i now have to take that back (somewhat confused by the *ranking* term; but it's more an assignment problem, not a ranking one)! **I think your solution is correct and among the most efficient in theory and practice!**. I did implement it in [python](https://gist.github.com/sschnug/85e1530214d65aef54374f3233b23a33). Only one thing is missing in your answer: **integrality-theorem** (as we don't want partial/splitted assignments). This answer is still highly underrated and i learned something!

Comment: The Google solver only allows integer flow quantities, so integrality is automatically satisfied with that particular library.  But you're right, other libraries may not provide that guarantee.

Comment: It's not about the implementation, but about the theoretical-framework. Not all flow-problems are needed to be solved to integrality. But when solving assignment problems this is important. I'm just saying, the answer is missing to mention that it will find an integral solution.